# Exceptional solutions to ODE

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to find the general solution for $y'=2(1-y^2)$ such that it also contains the solutions $y=\pm1$. I managed to arrive at $$\frac{\ln|y+1|-\ln|y-1|}{2}=2x+C$$ which gives $$\frac{y+1}{y-1}=Ae^{4x}$$ which further gives $$\frac{2}{y-1}=Ae^{4x}-1$$ so $$y=\frac{2}{Ae^{4x}-1}+1$$. 
Now, what I'm unsure about is how to check if this solution satisfies the exceptional
solutions since the derivative is an expression containing only the variable $x$ and I'm trying to check if $y=\pm1$ satisfies the ODE. I'm also not sure how I would modify the solution so that it also contains the exceptional solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: What happens in the general solution if $A=0$ or $A\to \infty$?

Comment: $y=-1$ or $y \rightarrow 1$. Would I have to similarly check what happens to the derivative for $y=\pm1$?

Comment: The derivative is given by $y' = 2(1-y^2)$ so if $y =-1$ and $y\to 1$ are cosidered the derivative is given by $y' =0$ or $y'\to 0$, which is obvious because these solutions are stationary points of the ODE.

Comment: Yeah I know what $y'$ is supposed to be from the ODE but I was confused about how exactly I would check if my general solution satisfied the exceptional solutions. Would I just have to observe what happens to $y'$ from my solution as $A=0$ or $A \rightarrow \infinity$?

Comment: You could ask your teaching assistants if that is enough for them, or if they require something special? Depending on the course you are taking the answer can be very different.